# j2me PushRegistry.RegisterAlarm and code signing

Tags: java-me, nokia, code-signing, midp, midlet

I am developing an app on Nokia C2-00
in which I am using push registry for auto start of app on some fixed time

ex.

```
PushRegistry.registerAlarm("ClassName",  alarm.getTime());
```

this is working perfect and it starts app on that time.

But this is asking me for permissions two times.

1. when I am registering alarm using
   `PushRegistry.registerAlarm("ClassName",  alarm.getTime());`
2. when app start on that defined time.

in [this](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/API_access_rights_on_phones,_Series_40_6th) and [this](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Java_Security_Domains) link I found that if my application is signed then it will not ask for permission when app autostart.

but I am not sure about the time when my code will register alarm.

Will it ask for permission or not?

Comment: Why not try it by yourself if you have a suitable device ?

Comment: i have device but i don't have Security Certificates. so i just want to confirm that if it is possible then and only then i want to purchase verysign certificates.